# How to (re)start Postgres on Windows command line in background?

Tags: postgresql, startup

My local Postgres server is configured to start when the computer starts. I just changed `postgresql.conf` file and had to restart the server. I did:

```
pg_ctl restart
```

from the command line BUT that started the server on the next command prompt:

```
pg_ctl: old server process (PID: 2968) seems to be gone
starting server anyway
server starting

D:\>2016-10-12 16:24:48 EDT LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector proces
2016-10-12 16:24:48 EDT HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "pg_log".
```

If I `ctrl-c` out of it or close the command window, that closes the server. How can I use `pg_ctl` to (re)start the server in the background, emulating how it works by default (as a Windows service)?

Comment: If Postgres is registered as a Windows **service** you should use `net stop` and `net start` to stop and start it. **Not** `pg_ctl`

Comment: what is the name of the service ?

Comment: You should know that, you installed it. You can check in with `services.msc` typically it's `postgresql-9.5` (or whatever version you are using)

Comment: yeah, i got it by going into windows services (postgresql-x64-9.6).  i'm just not that familiar with windows...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it [turns out](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html), it was running in the console because I didn't tell it where to stream the log. The following sent the process in the background:

```
pg_ctl restart -l %PGDATA%\server.log
```

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in answers. If your answer is the solution to your original question, please accept it when the system permits that, but as for your new question, please remove it from the answer and submit it as a proper new question. You can include a link to this one into it if the two are related and you believe that would help to understand the new question better. Thank you.

Comment: Note: even when I specify a log file, it still shuts down the server when I subsequently hit ctrl-c on the command line.

Comment: Also, there was a whole thread on what changes to make with respect to this issue; I can't tell what the consensus was, whether they ever fixed it.  https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1835410